# Find base address for a module using WinDbg

Tags: windbg

How can I determine the base address of a particular module (say, for instance, ntoskrnl.exe) in WinDbg? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lm` (list modules) shows the information for DLLs. You can filter by name using `lm m <name>`, e.g.

```
0:000> lm m ntdll
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
77b90000 77d33000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          d:\debug\symbols\wntdll.pdb\1074039C87B27BF997A06A9E2B1C84E61\wntdll.pdb
```

The number in the "start" column is the base address. You can confirm that it's just a different term by using `!lmi`. The output of that command explicitly mentions "Base address":

```
0:000> !lmi ntdll
Loaded Module Info: [ntdll] 
         Module: ntdll
   Base Address: 77b90000
[...]
```

In fact, the name of the module itself can be used as the base address, so you don't actually need to copy/paste, type or remember the base address. E.g. instead of

```
0:000> db 77b90000 L2
77b90000  4d 5a                                            MZ
```

you can also use

```
0:000> db ntdll L2
77b90000  4d 5a                                            MZ
```

(actually the example with `!lmi` used that trick already)